# How can two processes share the same Shared Library?

Tags: unix, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, position-independent-code, got

I've been trying to get a better grasp of how shared libraries work but I just can't rap my head around two things.

1- Each process has its own virtual memory space and page table, so If a shared library gets loaded into one process virtual memory space then how can a second process access that shared library since it's not in its memory space?

2- I understand that only the text section is shared while global data is not, how is this possible? My understanding is that each reference to a global variable is done via the [Global Offset Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Offset_Table) (GOT for short). So, if I have this line of code `x = glob` then this will roughly equal something like `mov eax,DWORD PTR [ecx-0x10]` in assembly, where `ecx` is used as the base value for the GOT. But if this is the case, then it is obvious that no matter which process calls that line, it will always access the same global variable whose address is at offset 0x10 in the GOT. So how can two processes have different copies of global variable, if they use the same text section that references the same GOT entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably you understand page tables and copy-on-write semantics.

Suppose you run an executable `a.out`, which initializes some global data, and then `fork()`s. You should have little trouble understanding that all read-only (e.g. code) pages of the `a.out` are now shared between two processes (the *exact same* pages of physical memory are `mmap`ed into both virtual memory spaces).

Now suppose that `a.out` also used `libc.so.6` before `fork`ing. You should have no trouble understanding that the read-only pages belonging to `libc.so.6` are also shared between processes in exactly the same fashion.

Now suppose that you have two separate executables, `a.out` and `b.out`, both using `libc.so.6`. Suppose a.out runs first. The dynamic loader will perform a read-only mapping of `libc.so.6` into `a.out` virtual memory space, and now some of its pages are in physical memory. At that point, `b.out` starts, and the dynamic loader `mmap` the same `libc.so.6` pages into its virtual memory. Since the kernel already has a mapping for these pages, there is no reason for the kernel to create new physical pages to hold the mapping -- it can re-use previously mapped physical pages. The end result is the same as for the `fork`ed binary -- the same physical pages are *shared* between multiple virtual memory spaces (and multiple processes).

> So how can two processes have different copies of global variable,

Very simple: the read-write mappings (which are required for *writable* data) are *not* shared between processes (so that one process can write to the variable, and that write will not be visible to the other process).

Comment: You've really cleared up my confusion of the first part, thank you. But the second part is still foggy. You mention "(so that one process can write to the variable, and that write will not be visible to the other process)." But how is this possible? is it something like each process gets its own GOT table, so that entry at offset `0x10` in one process contains a different value than in the other processes?

Comment: @GamefanA GOT is writable data, so yes: every process gets its own copy.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, GOT stores offset, and you need a base address to access each entry of GOT. Remember that all addresses we are talking about here are virtual addresses, so different processes can map the same virtual addresses to different physical addresses, which is the case for global variables. However, it is not the case for shared library, it resides in the same physical memory address for all processes.